# Orden de ejecución con FS y res.send

Tags: express, filesystem

Quisiera saber cómo hacer para que estos bloques de código me devuelvan el objeto a través de res.send.

Este es mi método

```
     getAllArchivo(){
    console.log('entra getall')
    let info = []
    fs.readFile('productos.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        info= JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("dentro del readfile")
        console.log(info)
    
        
      });

      return [...info]
     
}
```

Este es mi get

```
app.get('/productos', (req,res) => {
myObject = c.getAllArchivo()
console.log("mi objeto: " + myObject)
res.send(myObject)
```

Se ejecuta en el siguiente orden al realizar la petición

Servidor http escuchando en el puerto 8081
entra getall
mi objeto:
dentro del readfile
[
{
title: 'escuadra',
precio: 440,
thumbnail: 'https://www.google.cl',
id: '1'
},
{
title: 'calculadora',
precio: 1300,
thumbnail: 'https://www.youtube.cl',
id: '2'
},
{
title: 'globo terráqueo',
precio: 5456,
thumbnail: 'https://www.twitter.com',
id: '3'
}
]

Como ven, devuelve al final el objeto vacío porque la lectura no se ha finalizado en el método ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que devuelva lo que lee?

Comment: El problema es de asincronía. La lectura de archivos se realiza de forma asíncrona, por lo cual el orden en que se muestran los logs no es el mismo orden en el que están escritos.

Comment: Sí Mauricio, el asunto es que cómo resuelvo ese problema para que no lo devuelva vacío